# Float sibiling takes full width and height

Tags: html, css, css-float

Hee all,

With the following html and css structure

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 100px;">
            <div style="float: left; width: 80px; height: 100px; background-color: aqua;"></div>
            <div id="text">
                Hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When inspecting the page you can see that the div with `id=text` will take the full width and height of the parent. Does someone know why this happens?

Comment: i think this will clear your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970631/why-the-float-css-attribute-influence-parent-sibling-div#answer-40970880

Answer (score 0):

Elements next to a floating element will flow around it. To avoid this, use the clear property.

```
div#text {
    clear: both;
}
```